# Accessing Tale 2,600

Tags: tales-of-arabian-nights

**Is there a way to access passage 2,600 in *The Book of Tales* through normal play?**

Passage 2,600 in *The Book of Tales* appears to be a humorous easter egg referencing the fact that it is the last passage in the book and congratulating you for reaching it.  Can this passage be accessed through any adventures in the game, or is it simply a joke to be found by those who happen to read it (by accident or otherwise)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, your intuition is correct. It's an unreachable easter egg. [Kevin Maroney](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamedesigner/39260/kevin-maroney), developer of the 2nd and 3rd editions of Tales of the Arabian Nights, states [in this BGG thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/434003/entry-2600):

> Nope. It's an unreachable Easter Egg, a tradition going back to the first edition in 1985 (paragraph 1400) and continued in the 1999 second edition (paragraph 1600).

Comment: Not so unfortunate!  I think it's an amusing addition. =)